# Backbone recommends inserting all models when the page is generated on the server side

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm a noob with backbone. Came across this advice following [Addy Osmani's Book:](http://addyosmani.com/backbone-fundamentals/#connect-to-the-database)

Can somebody please help me understand this? If the server is pushing the models as part of page generation (say through `JSP`) how can model data end up in a `backbone model` on the client side?

I can understand HTML templating and dynamic insertion of data through `<% %>` tags from the server, but how to set up a `backbone model`? Unless it is fetched from the client itself?

**Following is the excerpt from the book:**

> The Backbone documentation recommends inserting all models when the page is generated on the server side, rather than fetching them from the client side once the page is loaded. Since this chapter is trying to give you a more complete picture of how to communicate with a server, we will go ahead and ignore that recommendation.

Comment: Can you quote the part of book that made you think in such a way..? Because backbone models and collections fetch data using ajax, and addy osmani is no noob :)

Comment: @TJ, I have updated the question, please take a look. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please ignore that paragraph.

I've been developing backbone apps for more than an year and haven't seen such thing in the docs or came across such a scenario.

[Backbone.js docs](http://backbonejs.org/) starts with:

> Backbone.js gives structure to web applications by providing models with key-value binding and custom events, collections with a rich API of enumerable functions, views with declarative event handling, and connects it all to your existing API over a **RESTful JSON** interface (*emphasis mine*).

Further [quotes](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-View-separation):

> A Model manages an internal table of data attributes, and triggers "change" events when any of its data is modified. Models handle syncing data with a persistence layer — **usually a REST API** with a backing database.

and further from [API-integration](http://backbonejs.org/#API-integration):

> Backbone is pre-configured to sync with a **RESTful API**.

No, The Backbone documentation doesn't particularly recommend crunching HTML and  inserting all models on the server side.

If you look at the way the [router](http://backbonejs.org/#Routing) is designed, you'll see it's primarily designed for SPA's (Singpe Page Applications) based on hash changes.

And well, there is no html coming from server at all when we talk about hybrid applications.

So ignore that comment without worries :) .